# Spring : How to return base64 image in @RestController

Tags: java, html, spring, image, base64

I have base64 String and I want to print base64 image on img tag using Spring's restcontroller.

I'm developing the front and the back separately.

this is my restcontroller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@Validated
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/image/test",  method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public byte[] getImage() throws Exception {

        String base64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAYIAAACzCAY...."; //from DB

        byte[] decodeBase64 = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);
        
        return decodeBase64;

    }
}
```

this is my html

```
<html>
 <body>
   <img src="http://localhost:8080/myProject/image/test"/>
 <body/>
</html>
```

The image is not output. What's the problem?

Comment: Read about "data URLs" and then see if you can determine what part of that string you need to be working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, just remove `data:image/png;base64,` part from your string. This is because you are using bytes and not base64 string in your `img src`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public byte[] getImage() {
        String base64 = "<BASE64 STRING WITHOUT `data:image/png;base64,` part>";
        byte[] decodeBase64 = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);

        return decodeBase64;
    }
```

And your html will remain intact.

```
<html>
<body>
<img src=http://localhost:8080/image />
<body/>
</html>
```